# Java Annotation Interface

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a set of classes I would like to require a certain method implemented with Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation.  I don't want a default defined, I just want to require that the annotation is used on a certain method.

Is this possible either through Interfaces or abstract classes?

Comment: No, it's not possible to require an annotation. You'd need to run a customizable code analysis tool to apply such checks.

Comment: Indeed, or something using Java's Reflection API's. But that's usually something to avoid so tread with care.